# How to reference form field created by AngularJS formly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I use Formly for creating my forms in angularJS

**This is my field**

```
$scope.postFields = [
    {
        key: 'title',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
            label: "Title",
            // required: true,
            minlength: 2,
        },
        validation: {
            messages: {
                required: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
                    return scope.to.label + ' is required'
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**and I'm trying to access my fields as follows**

```
    function failure(response) {
    console.log("failure", response)

    _.each(response.data, function(errors, key) {
        _.each(errors, function(e) {
            $scope.form[key].$dirty = true;
            $scope.form[key].$setValidity(e, false);
        });
    });
}
```

**my formly form**

```
<formly-form form="postForm" model="model" fields="postFields" class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addPost()">Submit</button>
</formly-form>
```

but of course I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

it's on this line

```
$scope.form[key].$dirty = true;
```

do anyone of you know how to reference created formly fields the right way?

Comment: Show us the place the error is at(I presume addPost)

Comment: Just edited question

Comment: where's your form tag?

Comment: just added it tot the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to reference the fields from the form, you could provide a `name` attribute to your fields. The `name` is generated by default. It's one of the nice things that angular-formly provides (you don't have to think about it). But if you want to reference it directly with a specific `key` (as you are) then you'd be best served by providing one yourself.

So you'd do something like this:

```
$scope.postFields = [
    {
        key: 'title',
        name: 'title',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
            label: "Title",
            // required: true,
            minlength: 2,
        },
        validation: {
            messages: {
                required: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
                    return scope.to.label + ' is required'
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Alternatively, you could create a [`fieldTransform`](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/very-advanced/field-transform) to do this automatically (just assign the name the same as the key). Or in your error handler, you could look up the `NgModelController` from the field's [`formControl`](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/field-configuration-object#formcontrol-ngmodelcontroller) property like this:

```
function handleError(fields, response) {
  _.each(fields, function(field) {
    if (response.data[field.key]) {
      field.formControl.$setDirty()
      _.each(response.data[field.key], function(e) {
        field.formControl.$setValidity(e, false)
      })
    }
  })
}
```

That's probably the best solution :-) Good luck!

Comment: P.S. if you're actually doing your validation messages like that, you may be interested in [this](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formlyvalidationmessages)

Comment: oh that perfectly solves my problem :) And thanks for the doc reference :) U did truly great job with formly.